# CS0117 "Resource" does not contain a definition for "Xml"

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I create the settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_preferences_settings">
    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory android:title="Category 1">
        <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="key1"
            android:title="Switch Preference"
            android:summary="Switch Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
            android:key="key2"
            android:title="EditText Preference"
            android:summary="EditText Summary"
            android:dialogMessage="Dialog Message"
            android:defaultValue="Default value" />
        <android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key3"
            android:title="CheckBox Preference"
            android:summary="CheckBox Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Added the **preferenceTheme** in styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    .....

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/background3</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

The SettingsFragment

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Support.V7.Preferences;

namespace Aprepara.Droid.Activities.Fragments
{
    public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat
    {
        public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
        {
            AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.settings);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Log.Info("Aprepara.Droid", "SettingsFragment");
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.settings, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

but it is displaying the error that XML does not exist in Resource.

I'm using the example as a reference ...

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportpreferences?version=23.2.1

Can anybody help me? Why does the XML not exist in Resource?

[image]

Comment: And in which folder did you put your settings.xml?

Comment: In the layout folder. I added image with the folder structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it is displaying the error that XML does not exist in Resource.

Create a `xml` folder in your `Resourc`e folder and put your `settings.xml` in this `xml` folder.

Effect :

[image]

Comment: With the freshly updated VS 2017 15.7.0, the error is back, even though the `xml` folder is present under `Resources`. But this time the project still compiles even though the code editor keeps showing the red squiggly line and suggesting creating an `Xml` member in `Resource`.

Comment: @gserg did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @CHash_Mike https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/249090/xamarin-missing-definitions-of-xml-menu-possibly-o.html